# Bash Script to copy contents from one file to another

Tags: bash, file, loops

I am trying to create a script where it takes even number of file names, and copy contents from one file to another. for eg: if 4 file names are provided then content of 1 gets copied to file 2 and content of file 3 gets copied to file 4.

until now I could only think of..

```
if [ expr $# % 2 -ne 0 ]
then
echo: Please enter even number of filenames
exit
fi
for file in $*
do
.....
....
```

Please advise me how to proceed with this script..Thanks a lot in advance..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove files from the argument list as you use them, with the `shift` command:

```
if (( $# % 2 )); then
    echo Please enter an even number of filenames
    exit 1
fi

while (( $# )); do
    src=$1
    dst=$2
    cp "$src" "$dst"
    shift 2
done
```

Comment: @PaulRubel isnt the `shift 2` taking care of this?

Comment: Thanks @chepner, you are a star :)

Comment: One quick [stupid] question though.. what is the significance of double parenthesis here?, I tried its not working with one or no parenthesis..

Comment: `(( ... ))` is an arithmetic expression in `bash`. I used it as a simpler replacement for your test involving the `expr`. A more standard replacement would be `[ $( $# % 2 ) -ne 0 ]` ( `expr` is not needed for arithmetic in POSIX-compatible shells).

Comment: Ahh my bad...I was referring to the double parenthesis in while statement. I figured the test condition/if parenthesis. I am was not able to understand what significance it has with while loop... I tried with single parenthesis and it gave me "ambiguous redirect" error.

Comment: Same meaning in the while loop. It's an abbreviated form of the expression `(( $# > 0 ))`, since in an arithmetic expression, and non-zero value evaluates as true.

Comment: Thanks @chepner :) appreciate your help